# How to find the indices of the top 10,000 elements in a symmetric matrix(12k X 12k) in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a nonzero symmetric matrix 'matr' that is 12000X12000. I need to find the indices of the top 10000 elements in 'matr' in R. The code I have written takes a long time - I was wondering if there was any pointers to make it faster.

```
listk <- numeric(0)
for( i in 1:10000) {
    idx <- which(matr == max(matr), arr.ind=T)
    if( length(idx) != 0) {
        listk <- rbind( listk, idx[1,])
        matr[idx[1,1], idx[1,2]] <- 0
        matr[idx[2,1], idx[2,2]] <- 0
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late into the party, but I came up with this, which avoids the sort.

Say you want the top 10k elements from you 12k x 12k matrix. The idea is to "clip" the data to the elements corresponding to a quantile of that size.

```
find_n_top_elements <- function( x, n ){

  #set the quantile to correspond to n top elements
  quant <- n / (dim(x)[1]*dim(x)[2])

  #select the cutpoint to get the quantile above quant
  lvl <- quantile(x, probs=1.0-quant)

  #select the elements above the cutpoint
  res <- x[x>lvl[[1]]]
}

#create a 12k x 12k matrix (1,1Gb!)
n <- 12000
x <- matrix( runif(n*n), ncol=n)

system.time( res <- find_n_top_elements( x, 10e3 ) )
```

Resulting in

```
system.time( res <- find_n_top_elements( x, 10e3 ) )
 user  system elapsed
 3.47    0.42    3.89
```

For comparison, just sorting x on my system takes

```
system.time(sort(x))
   user  system elapsed 
  30.69    0.21   31.33
```

Answer (score 19):

Here's how you might find the indices (`ij`) of the 4 largest elements in a 10-by-10 matrix `m`.

```
## Sample data
m <- matrix(runif(100), ncol=10)

## Extract the indices of the 4 largest elements
(ij <- which(m >= sort(m, decreasing=T)[4], arr.ind=TRUE))
#      row col
# [1,]   2   1
# [2,]   5   1
# [3,]   6   2
# [4,]   3  10

## Use the indices to extract the values
m[ij]
#  [1] 0.9985190 0.9703268 0.9836373 0.9914510
```

---

**Edit:**

For large matrices, performing a partial sort will be a faster way to find the 10,000th largest element:

```
v <- runif(1e7)
system.time(a <- sort(v, decreasing=TRUE)[10000])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    4.35    0.03    4.38 
system.time(b <- -sort(-v, partial=10000)[10000])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.60    0.09    0.69 
a==b
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wouldnt sorting a 12k*12k matrix take a really long time?

Comment: @user1775614 -- It's not slow: `j <- runif(1e7); system.time(sort(j))` takes just about 4 seconds on my computer. Sorting your matrix does take too much memory on my (32-bit) computer. A 6000-by-6000 matrix *is* sortable though (in 17 seconds) so you could presumably split your matrix in 4, extract the top 10k elements from each, find the top 10k from among those 40k, and then return to the original matrix to find the indices of the largest 10k.

Comment: that helps! thanks! R is so counter intuitive. I thought iterating through it, would be faster than having R sort the matrix. Almost went back to writing code in C for it.

Comment: Somewhat along those lines, you might find [this post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/sorting/) interesting. (It shows how you could use C++ from within R to sort and then extract the nth element from an R vector object.) There is some speed advantages, but I'd be even more interested to learn whether that code gets you around R's memory limitation in this case.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien a second big memory use is `m >= ...`, making a logical matrix the same size as `m`, whereas what you want in the end is just an integer vector of length `n = 10000`. It would be natural to pre-allocate and fill the return vector iteratively in C / C++ and avoid the big memory allocation; probably the iteration would be prohibitively expensive in R? Also one might think of a data structure like a priority queue would have a reasonable implementation in C++ but would be difficult to implement efficiently in R.

Comment: @MartinMorgan -- Interesting points. Thanks. Within R, using `order()` avoids making the huge logical matrix: `ii <- order(m, decreasing=TRUE); arrayInd(ind=ii, .dim=c(<nrow>, <ncol>))`. Unfortunately, `order()` is a *lot* slower than `sort()` (150 seconds vs 25 seconds for a 5e7 long vector), so it isn't really a good option in most cases.

Comment: Actually, Memory is not huige deal cos I have access to a cluster art the university. I am running the sort() command on 12kX12k and it has been 20hours and it is still running. :(

Comment: Yeah, something is definitely wrong with that matrix (or your computer is thrashing on a too big matrix, or it's a cluster issue or something.)  Running this code will show you that a 5kX10k matrix (not *that much smaller* than yours) only takes on the order of a half-minute to sort: `m <- matrix(runif(5e7), ncol=5e3); system.time(sort(m))`.

Comment: Yea, I figured it out - for some reason, R os taking more thsn 20 hours to load the 12kX12k matrix from a 1gb file. C does it faster, so I just wrote some code to read the file in and extract the maximums. Thanks for all the help!!!

Answer (score 7):

I like @JoshO'Brien 's answer; the use of partial sorting is great! Here's an Rcpp solution (I'm not a strong C++ programmer so probably bone-headed errors; corrections welcome... how would I template this in Rcpp, to handle different types of input vector?)

I start by including the appropriate headers and using namespaces for convenience

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <queue>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
```

Then arrange to expose my C++ function to R

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector top_i_pq(NumericVector v, int n)
```

and define some variables, most importantly a `priority_queue` to hold as a pair the numeric value and index. The queue is ordered so the smallest values are at the 'top', with small relying on the standard pair<> comparator.

```
typedef pair<double, int> Elt;
priority_queue< Elt, vector<Elt>, greater<Elt> > pq;
vector<int> result;
```

Now I'll walk through the input data, adding it to the queue if either (a) I don't yet have enough values or (b) the current value is larger than the smallest value in the queue. In the latter case, I pop off the smallest value, and insert it's replacement. In this way the priority queue always contains the n_max largest elements.

```
for (int i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
    if (pq.size() < n)
        pq.push(Elt(v[i], i));
    else {
        Elt elt = Elt(v[i], i);
        if (pq.top() < elt) {
            pq.pop();
            pq.push(elt);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally I pop the indexes from the priority queue into the return vector, remembering to translate to 1-based R coordinates.

```
result.reserve(pq.size());
while (!pq.empty()) {
    result.push_back(pq.top().second + 1);
    pq.pop();
}
```

and return the result to R

```
return wrap(result);
```

This has nice memory use (the priority queue and return vector are both small relative to the original data) and is fast

```
> library(Rcpp); sourceCpp("top_i_pq.cpp"); z <- runif(12000 * 12000)
> system.time(top_i_pq(z, 10000))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.992   0.000   0.998
```

Problems with this code include:

1. The default comparator `greater<Elt>` works so that, in the case of a tie spanning the value of the _n_th element, the last, rather than first,  duplicate is retained.
2. NA values (and non-finite values?) may not be handled correctly; I'm not sure whether this is true or not.
3. The function only works for `NumericVector` input, but the logic is appropriate for any R data type for which an appropriate ordering relationship is defined.

Problems 1 and 2 can likely be dealt with by writing an appropriate comparator; maybe for 2 this is already implemented in Rcpp? I don't know how to leverage C++ language features and the Rcpp design to avoid re-implementing the function for each data type I want to support.

Here's the full code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <queue>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector top_i_pq(NumericVector v, int n)
{
    typedef pair<double, int> Elt;
    priority_queue< Elt, vector<Elt>, greater<Elt> > pq;
    vector<int> result;

    for (int i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
        if (pq.size() < n)
            pq.push(Elt(v[i], i));
        else {
            Elt elt = Elt(v[i], i);
            if (pq.top() < elt) {
                pq.pop();
                pq.push(elt);
            }
        }
    }

    result.reserve(pq.size());
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        result.push_back(pq.top().second + 1);
        pq.pop();
    }

    return wrap(result);
}
```

Comment: nice. I did not see this before. I'll play with this and let you know if I can improve on it. templating it for numeric and integer cases should not be too hard.

Comment: Luckily, `evalCpp( NA_REAL > 2.0 )` gives `FALSE` and so does `evalCpp( NA_INTEGER > 2 )` so indices for missing values won't enter the queue.

Comment: For more on this approach, and a templated generalization of it, see [this post in the Rcpp gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/top-elements-from-vectors-using-priority-queue/),

Answer (score 1):

Matrix in R is like a vector.

```
mat <- matrix(sample(1:5000, 10000, rep=T), 100, 100)
mat.od <- order(mat, decreasing = T)
mat.od.arr <- cbind(mat.od%%nrow(mat), mat.od%/%nrow(mat)+1)
mat.od.arr[,2][mat.od.arr[,1]==0] <- mat.od.arr[,2][mat.od.arr[,1]==0] - 1
mat.od.arr[,1][mat.od.arr[,1]==0] <- nrow(mat)
head(mat.od.arr)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   58    5
# [2,]   59   72
# [3,]   38   22
# [4,]   23   10
# [5,]   38   14
# [6,]   90   15

mat[58, 5]
# [1] 5000
mat[59, 72]
# [1] 5000
mat[38, 22]
# [1] 4999
mat[23, 10]
# [1] 4998
```