# finding first three maximum element and their index of a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector which looks like this

```
[12,3,4,5,6,7,8,12]
```

I want to find the index and the value of first three maximum number.The maximum number can also repeat like above vector 12 repeats .

I used

> which

but it only returns index for one number how can this be done

**The output**

```
[12,12,8]
[1,8,7]
```

I also read this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450778/r-fastest-way-to-get-the-indices-of-the-max-n-elements-in-a-vector) but it did not help

Comment: See function `sort.int` and its arguments `decreasing` and `index.return`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x <- c(12, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12)
sort.int(x, decreasing = TRUE, index.return = TRUE)
# $x
# [1] 12 12  8  7  6  5  4  3

# $ix
# [1] 1 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
```

Then, the first three elements:

```
sort.int(x, decreasing = TRUE, index.return = TRUE)$ix[1:3]
# [1] 1 8 7
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `sort` and `sort.int` besides `sort.int` not working for multiple columns in data.frames? like `sort.int` beeing faster?

Comment: i am not the original poster, I just wanted to know why you used `sort.int` instead of `sort`, what advantages this has

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. It is almost exactly the same. You can find more details reading `?sort`. But basically, in most cases, you can use `sort(x, decreasing = TRUE, index.return = TRUE)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

just sort the vector in decreasing order and select the first three items:

```
vec <- c(12,3,4,5,6,7,8,12)

# gives the biggest three elements
sort(vec, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]
# gives the indices of the first three elements
order(vec, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]
```