# Select top 5 highest columns along 1 row in R

Tags: r

I have a single row dataframe with 65 columns....each containing a single numeric.
I want to make another single row dataframe that has only the top 5 columns (highest numerical values) from the original dataframe.
How do i do this in R..?

```
x <- data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,g=7,h=8,i=9,j=10)
```

for example I just want the top 5 cols.

Paul.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example.

Comment: An easy way would be to arrange the column based on their values i.e. descending order and just select first 5 columns.

Comment: Yes - how do I do that, order by column..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the indices of the top 10,000 elements in a symmetric matrix(12k X 12k) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821859/how-to-find-the-indices-of-the-top-10-000-elements-in-a-symmetric-matrix12k-x-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SaurabhChauchan suggested, the easiest way would be to order your columns and only select the first 5 ones:

```
## The data frame
x <- data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,g=7,h=8,i=9,j=10)

#  a b c d e f g h i  j
#1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10


## Selecting the five columns with the highest value
sort(x[1,], decreasing = TRUE)[1:5]

#   j i h g f
#1 10 9 8 7 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly go through the following code.

```
x <- data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,g=7,h=8,i=9,j=10)
x

  a b c d e f g h i  j
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

# Order the row by sorting the columns i.e. Descending order
(x[,order(-x[nrow(x),])])[1:5]

# Display only first five columns with Highest values

   j i h g f
1 10 9 8 7 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tidyverse` approach.

```
require(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,g=7,h=8,i=9,j=10)

x %>% 
  gather(var, value) %>% 
  arrange(value) %>% 
  tail()

   var value
5    e     5
6    f     6
7    g     7
8    h     8
9    i     9
10   j    10
```